# Код на C++ выводит не верный результат

Tags: c++

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Point{
protected:
 int x, y;
 friend void distance(Point &, Point &, Point &);
public:
 Point(){
  x=0;
  y=0;
 }
 Point(int x, int y){
  this->x=x;
  this->y=y;
 }
};


void distance(Point &p1, Point &p2, Point &p3){
 float fp, sp, tp;
 fp=sqrt(pow((p2.x-p1.x),2)+pow((p2.y-p1.y),2));
 sp=sqrt(pow((p3.x-p2.x),2)+pow((p3.y-p2.y),2));
 tp=sqrt(pow((p1.x-p3.x),2)+pow((p1.y-p3.y),2));
 cout<<"Первая точка:"<<fp<<endl;
 cout<<"Первая точка:"<<sp<<endl;
 cout<<"Первая точка:"<<tp<<endl;
}

void area(float fp, float sp, float tp){
    float p, res;
    p=(fp+sp+tp)/2;
    res=sqrt(p*(p-fp)*(p-sp)*(p-tp));
}

int main() {
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
 int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
 float fp, sp, tp, res;
 cout << "***********************************" << endl;
 cout << "Введите координаты первой точки(X): ";
 cin >> x1;
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Введите координаты первой точки(Y): ";
 cin >> y1;
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Введите координаты второй точки(X): ";
 cin >> x2;
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Введите координаты второй точки(Y): ";
 cin >> y2;
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Введите координаты третьей точки(X): ";
 cin >> x3;
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Введите координаты третьей точки(Y): ";
 cin >> y3;
 cout << "\n";

 Point firstpoint(x1, y1);
 Point secondpoint(x2, y2);
 Point thirdpoint(x3, y3);
 distance(firstpoint, secondpoint, thirdpoint);
 area(fp, sp, tp);
 cout<<"Площа трикутника:"<<res<<endl;


 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

А у вас результата просто нет. Вот тут

```
void area(float fp, float sp, float tp){
    float p, res;
    p=(fp+sp+tp)/2;
    res=sqrt(p*(p-fp)*(p-sp)*(p-tp));
}
```

вы считаете, считаете, присваиваете результат локальной переменной `res` и выходите из функции. `res` просто выброшена.

А тут

```
cout<<"Площа трикутника:"<<res<<endl;
```

выводите значение совсем другой `res`, объявленной тут

```
float fp, sp, tp, res;
```

и даже не инициализированной (о чем должен предупредить компилятор), т.е. содержащей какой-то мусор...

Примерно та же ерунда и с `distance`...

Как исправить ситуацию - сами разберетесь или нет?

**Update**

Посмотрите, что исправлено и как, обязательно разберитесь во всех изменениях!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Point{
protected:
    int x, y;
    friend double distance(Point, Point);
public:
    Point(int x = 0, int y= 0):x(x),y(y){}
};

double distance(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)*(p2.x-p1.x)+(p2.y-p1.y)*(p2.y-p1.y));
}

double area(double fp, double sp, double tp)
{
    double p = (fp+sp+tp)/2.0;
    return sqrt(p*(p-fp)*(p-sp)*(p-tp));
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    cout << "***********************************" << endl;
    cout << "Введите координаты первой точки(X): ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите координаты первой точки(Y): ";
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите координаты второй точки(X): ";
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите координаты второй точки(Y): ";
    cin >> y2;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите координаты третьей точки(X): ";
    cin >> x3;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите координаты третьей точки(Y): ";
    cin >> y3;
    cout << "\n";

    Point firstpoint(x1, y1);
    Point secondpoint(x2, y2);
    Point thirdpoint(x3, y3);

    cout << "Площа трикутника:" <<
        area(distance(firstpoint,secondpoint),
             distance(firstpoint,thirdpoint),
             distance(secondpoint,thirdpoint)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: У меня не очень с этим кодом всё хорошо получается, буду очень благодарен если объясните

Answer (score 0):

> Код на C++ выводит не верный результат

да разве?

комментарий пока не могу оставить...
что бы понять где ошибка, если бы код возможно было бы скомпилировать нужно воспользоваться отладчиком.
а если посмотреть на код, то Вы пытаетесь передать в функцию `area` неинициализированные переменные, а в следующей строке такую же неинициализированную переменную `res`, поэтому то код и не компилируется...
если это "исправить", то тогда и будет выводить неверный результат:

функция `area` объявленна как void, исходя из того, что она "считает", то она должна вернуть какое-то значение и судя по "коду" это должно быть значение `res=sqrt(p*(p-fp)*(p-sp)*(p-tp));`, которое вы пытаетесь вывести `cout<<"Площа трикутника:"<<res<<endl;`
а если копнуть ещё глубже, то и в функции `distance`, значения `fp, sp, tp` никуда не сохраняются, а это значит, что использовние этих переменных в качестве параметров для функции `area` не имеет смысла.

Comment: я бы создал бы "структуру/класс" с переменными fp, sp, tp, и тогда функция  distance должна была бы вернуть объект структуры/класса, а функция area, в таком случае возвращала бы значение res(float/double), и принимала бы в качестве параметра объект структуры/класса